# What kind of shrub with long green spiky leaves is this?

Tags: identification, perennials

[image]

I got stuck in the forehead by one of the spines Wednesday and it is still sore. It bled a lot Wednesday. Yesterday I popped it and some pus came out. It is still red and sore. I just want to check and make sure the spines are not poisonous or anything. This tree is in our back yard. We live in Anderson, SC. It was something my father-in-law had planted years ago. We live in the house now. My mother said it was a palm, but that's all she knows.

Comment: With [tag:identification] questions, it's useful to describe where in the world you found the plant, and the conditions where you found it (sun, shade, rocky hillside, forested riverbank, and so on). If you have more information about the plant, please update your question to add it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is a member of the [Yucca](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Yucca) genus.  There are numerous species with a wide range from Central America to southern Canada. Although the spiky leaves are a hazard the large white flowering stalk is very attractive and these plants are grown and planted for the landscape trade.

It is not poisonous and a little first aid should resolve your wound.

If this plant is poorly situated near your house a bit of work with scissors will cut down on the sharp points of the leaves.  If it's not on your property then giving it a wide berth will have to do.

Answer (score 4):

yep a type of yucca plant.
[image: trim close to the surface with kitchen shears or hand trimmers with gloves][image: Yucca aloifolia is what this type is called]

this is how it looks trimmed. the points on the leaf tips are very skin irritating. I use a warm poultice of plantain leaves cuts down the redness and swelling. I had trimmed these as a job. I always use thick leather gloves around these plants.

[image: here is another way to trim it]

Comment: can you upload the picture here as it really helps your answer and links to other sites can go stale